# Where can i find the div defined for the operations menu in yii.?

Tags: php, html, yii

Can anybody tell me where can i find the `div` for the `operations` menu (the one in red in the image) in yii, I looked every where but could not find it.
Here is the screenshot:
[image: Operations Menu]

Thanks.

Comment: in your views/cotroller_name/admin.php, find sidebar array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output for this is generated in `protected/views/layouts/column2.php`. If you have installed a Bootstrap theme the path can be `themes/bootstrap/views/layouts/column2.php`.

The output is generated by the `CPortlet` (This creates the box) and the `CMenu` (This creates the links) widgets. You can use this article to style the CMenu:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/525/customizing-the-cmenu-widget/

The CPortlet can be styled by setting a CSS class via the [htmlOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPortlet#htmlOptions-detail).

Comment: Then you have the first file (`protected/views/layouts/column2.php`). See my updated anwser how to style this.

Answer (score 0):

In your views folder, find `admin.php` file.

In `admin.php`, you can see:

```
$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Create New Company', 'url'=>array('create'))    
);
```

You can change the style in your layout view file.

Comment: I want to remove this div and add my own div custom div..how do i do that?

Comment: you can do customization in layouts/your_layout_name.php. If it is column 2, then protected/views/layouts/column2.php

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you want to find but if you want to find out the class or ID of the div wrapping the portlet then you can **right click the browser, click view source** and then you can find out the class or id of your desired div and then you can add it in your css or javascript code .